# Reboot Windows 10 PC remotely

Tags: windows-10, reboot, remote-control

I have VPN access to a different network and I'm able to connect to it just fine. However, I need to reboot one PC on this VPN-connected data network.

I had a ***TeamViewer*** Host Session established, but it's not allowing me to connect and ***Remote Desktop*** won't connect either. So, I'm unable to remotely access the PC, and I can't reboot it since I'm not onsite—that's a 3 hour drive.

Is there a way I can send a reboot command to that PC?

Comment: If this might be a situation that may regularly repeat, here are some techniques.  For some of these, first, determine the security considerations of setting this up.  A) Use more than TeamViewer.  Install multiple remote access techniques.  B) Find out who can remotely reboot, or power cycle, the device.  C) Use a UPS that allows a remote HTTPS/HTTP/Telnet/etc. connection.  Then the UPS can signal the computer, which may shutdown/restart due to a signal coming from the UPS (if the system has drivers).  Or UPS can power off.  May need not-cheapest UPS; but still be cheaper than 3hr trips.

Comment: 1. Open Powershell on your host computer
2. Type this

`Restart-Computer remote-ip -Force -Credential domain\username`

3. Enter password

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> **Reboot Windows 10 PC remotely**

Here are some potential considerations for this task:

1. You should have someone with physical access reboot the machine for you that is there physically in case there's a boot issue and you cannot access it otherwise remotely.
2. You can run the `SHUTDOWN -m \\<PCName> -r -f` (or `SHUTDOWN -m \\<IPAddress> -r -f`) to force a reboot remotely.

> **Note:** If you are in another domain or with a different user you can use:
>
> `runas /netonly /user:domain\username "cmd /c shutdown -m \\ipaddress -r -f"`

- You'll want to do this from another machine that can access this with appropriate permissions to run this command.

  - I usually do a `PING -t <PCName>` right after this until it starts responding, give it a few for things to fully start, then  RDP, etc.
  - If it hoses up during the reboot, you may need to get someone to hard boot it, or take the dreaded drive anyway.

---

### PowerShell (Bonus Solution)

```
Restart-Computer -ComputerName <PCName> -Force -AsJob;
```

Or the below syntax with a different credential with access to the remote system

```
Restart-Computer -ComputerName <PCName> -Force -AsJob -Credential (Get-Credential);
```

---

### Further Resources

- [Shutdown](http://ss64.com/nt/shutdown.html)
- [Restart-Computer](https://ss64.com/ps/restart-computer.html)
- [Get-Credential](https://ss64.com/ps/get-credential.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use Alt-F4 from the remote machine's desktop.

That brings up a "Shut Down Windows" window with a combo box for the different shutdown options (Disconnect, Sign Out, Sleep, Shut Down, and Restart).  If you use Alt-F4 with an application open, it shuts down that application.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. OP says "I'm unable to remotely access the PC"

Comment: Sorry.  I saw the last line "Is there a way I can send a reboot command to that PC?"  and the title and assumed they were trying to reboot the remote machine.

Comment: They *are* trying to reboot the remote machine *because* TeamViewer and RDP stopped working.