# Remote Shutdown via CMD does not work

Tags: windows-10, remote-shutdown

If I try to shutdown a computer in my LAN via the `shutdown /m 192.168.55.57 /s` command, the following message appears.

> 192.168.55.141: Access denied(5)

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you launching command prompt as an administrator? Are you on a domain?

Comment: It is not working when we launch it as administrator.

Comment: You need to be administrator on the remote computer for this to be allowed. Either become a domain admin or get your user or a usersgroup that you are a member of (such as DOMAIN\Users) in the administrators group on that pc.

Comment: How could I create a domain admin? We already googled it, but found nothing.

Comment: I wrote about this a long time ago here: https://superuser.com/questions/1038571/reboot-windows-10-pc-remotely/1038573#1038573 Follow these steps and see if that helps any.

Answer (score 0):

The correct credentials are not being used. Assuming that you have the credentials of a user authorized to perform a shutdown, run this command on the local computer first:

net use \\192.168.55.57 /u:USERNAME *

Enter the password when prompted. You should note that the username should have the computer name in it (i.e DESKTOP7\Username). After this command is run, windows should use the correct credentials and the shutdown should work.

Answer (score -1):

On your destination machines, do the following:

1. Open Note Pad
2. Save as LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy.bat
3. Right Click and select Edit and paste the following

REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" /v LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f

Save and right click and Run as Administrator on the destination PC. This should resolve the issue.